# Unity2D Vector2 adds up to infinity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

I'm currently implementing a movable gravity well that the player controls in Unity3D. The player can also add on an offset vector to the force of gravity that will affect its movement so it doesn't always go towards the center of the gravity well. Using these forces, I can determine the velocity each entity affected by the gravity well should go and its trajectory; however, `attributes.trajectory` is continually added up until it reaches either +/- infinity and crashed the game. Logs show that that `gravityTrajectory` and `gravityOffset` are at the correct vectors and speed at the time of crash is about 30 units. The logs show that `attributes.trajectory` isn't being properly normalized and will retain its magnitude. My question is why isn't `attributes.trajectory.Normalize()` properly normalizing the vector?

I would assume that normalizing a vector with infinite floats could cause a problem, but it should have normalized way before that. Any help trying to debug this problem is appreciated.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float gravityForce;
    float offsetForce;

    // calculate forces to apply.
    Vector2 gravityTrajectory = FindGravityVector(out gravityForce);
    Vector2 gravityOffset = FindGravityOffset(out offsetForce);

    // get new velocity from forces.
    speed += (gravityForce + offsetForce) * Time.deltaTime;

    // add current trajectory to current force vectors.
    attributes.trajectory += (gravityTrajectory + gravityOffset);
    attributes.trajectory.Normalize();

    // scale the trajectory by the velocity
    attributes.trajectory *= speed;

    // update position based on velocity
    rigidbody2D.MovePosition((transform.position + (Vector3)(attributes.trajectory)) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

EDIT 1:

Here is the method that finds the force of gravity:

```
private Vector2 FindGravityVector(out float gravityForce)
{
    Vector2 gravityTrajectory = (Vector2)(orb.transform.position - transform.position);
    gravityForce = MinionManager.Instance.gravity * orb.GetComponent<Orb>().Mass / Mathf.Pow(gravityTrajectory.magnitude, 2);
    return gravityTrajectory;
}
```

Here is what each attributes are at time of crash (according to Debug.Log):

> attributes.trajectory Before: (3419851000000000000.0, 762847100000000000.0)
>
> gravityTrajectory: (64.3, -28.1)
>
> gravityOffset: (0.0, 0.0)
>
> gravityForce: 0.02031127
>
> offsetForce: 0
>
> speed: 261.1045
>
> attributes.trajectory after: (892938500000000000000.0, 199182800000000000000.0)

Comment: Post your `FindGravityVector` and `FindGravityOffset` functions. It sounds like one of them is returning `Vector2` with infinity values and that is causing `attributes.trajectory` to have infinity values as well.

Comment: I posted `FindGravityVector` and not `FindGravityOffset` since the problem still occurs even if there isn't an offset.

Comment: In `FindGravityVector` if your `gravityTrajectory` is very small then your `gravityForce` will be very big. Also, if you're going to use `Mathf.Pow(gravityTrajectory.magnitude, 2);` you might as well just use `gravityTrajectory.sqrMagnitude` and skip the unnecessary square root operation.